# Solving the recurrence $T(n) = 2T(\frac{n}{4}) + (n^{0.5})$ with the Master theorem

Tags: algorithms

Would the result will be $\theta(^{0.5})$? This is what I found by using the second option of the master theorem.

Comment: Not quite, it is $\theta(n^{0.5}\lg n)$

Answer (score 0):

By using the Master theorem we have that:

$a=2,b=4$

$log_ba=0.5$ so $f(n)$ (which in your case is $n^{0.5}$) is $\Theta(n^{log_ba})$

Thus by falling in the second case of the Master Theorem:

$T(n)=\Theta(n^{log_ba}*log_bn)=\Theta(n^{0.5}*logn)=\Theta(\sqrt{n}*logn)$